# Booting a ppc linux kernel in qemu

Tags: linux, kernel, qemu, powerpc

i am new at this. 
I am trying to boot a linux kernel image cross compiled for powerpc inside qemu.
I followed guides on the web, but i am stuck and i don;t really know what do to next.

```
qemu-system-ppc -kernel vmlinux_2 -hda ss1.1.img -append "console=ttyS0 root=/dev/sda1" -nographic

>> =============================================================
>> OpenBIOS 1.1 [Jul 30 2013 21:44]
>> Configuration device id QEMU version 1 machine id 2
>> CPUs: 1
>> Memory: 128M
>> UUID: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
>> CPU type PowerPC,750
Welcome to OpenBIOS v1.1 built on Jul 30 2013 21:44
>> [ppc] Kernel already loaded (0x01000000 + 0x001e5608) (initrd 0x00000000 + 0x00000000)
>> [ppc] Kernel command line: console=ttyS0 root=/dev/sda1
```

from here on it does nothing, i can enter monitor mode but nothing. Nothing happens. I even tried to copy a fs to the img file hoping that smt would happen but nothing. 
If i run the command without the nographic option vnc only shows me a white screen with the bios version, and a blinking cursor.
Any ideeas / advice? 
I looked trough the qemu documentation, but the problem is i don't even know where i am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Looking your initrd output:

> (0x01000000 + 0x001e5608) (initrd 0x00000000 + 0x00000000)

It really does not look normal at all.

My bootup attempt:

```
qemu-system-ppc -m 1024 -kernel vmlinux -cdrom mini.iso -boot d
```

where the mini.iso, initrd.gz, vmlinux is loaded from here:

http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/xenial/main/installer-powerpc/current/images/powerpc/netboot

does work.   At the installation prompt, just enter "alt-F2" (or "alt-F3") to switch to another console and "dmesg" and you can see that the entire kernel has been successfully booted up.

The dmesg tail-end and starting lines are shown here:

[image]

Comment: i get a kernel panic running that :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when building a qemuppc image with Yocto. 
Please try to rebuild your kernel *without* this config - it solved the problem in my case:

- CONFIG_KEXEC

kexec is a system call that implements the ability to shutdown your current kernel, and to start another kernel. It is like a reboot but it is independent of the system firmware.

If you google "CONFIG_KEXEC PowerPC" you will also find some answers.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was when I built the kernel.  If I did not enable:
Platform support --->
  Support booting from Open firmware or yaboot
I got the exact same screen as you.  When I flipped it to on, rebuilt the kernel using bitbake virtual/kernel -c menuconfig for yocto/poky all was well!  :)

Answer (score 0):

OF[openfirmware] can't boot kdump kernel. qemuppc using openbios.

Answer (score -1):

Dont use `nographic`
use below command ,

`qemu-system-ppc -kernel vmlinux_2 -hda ss1.1.img -append "console=ttyS0 root=/dev/sda1"`

or

`qemu-system-ppc -kernel vmlinux_2 -hda ss1.1.img -append "root=/dev/sda1"`

Comment: Not working ...I tried those before, but i use -nographic for more output. however they do not work. I tried with root / console. Graphic/ no grpahic, network / no network but the result is always the same.

Comment: i dont about ppc Arcitecture, since in Arm -kernel zImage parameter is passed, can you through some light on -kernel vmlinux_2 in ppc

Comment: it's a linux kernel compiled for ppc(make ARCH=ppc CROS_COMPILE=$CC). a linux 2.6 kernel to be more exact. I think i am doing something wrong, i just can't figure out what.

Comment: returning 0x00000000 from prom_init  => this is what i get now.

Comment: which *_defconfig are u using while building means platform and machine name?

Comment: generic ppc and in cpu-s 6xx,7xx.....What is prom_init, i looked in the sources but my skills are not very good.